# Merge tag Pest with Pests

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I found that there are two tags for pests. Both [pest](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest) and [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests). I think it would be best if we could make [pest](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest) a synonym of [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out. I've merged the tags (since they mean exactly the same thing), which automatically creates a synonym so any future attempts to use [pest](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pest) will get the [pests](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pests) instead.